# Logon to a website and the use of jQuery and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, cross-domain

I have a information screen solution where a computer has a locally stored HTML page which loads an external template (including the functional Javascript etc.) into the browser.

The reason that this page is local is that if the computer is started when there is no network connection, or e.g. the server is down, it will retry over a period of time.

However, sometimes this computer needs to logon, so I pass the logon credentials and a cookie is based back.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    url = "http://192.168.1.27:9000/carousel/1/template?user=test&password=test";

    function loadTemplate() {
        $( "#error" ).html("Loading...");
        $( "#message" ).html("");
        $('body').load(url, function( response, status, xhr ) {
            if ( status == "error" ) {
                $( "#error" ).html("<h3>Sorry but there was an error:<br/></font></h3>" + " Description: " + xhr.statusText + " (" + xhr.status + ")");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

However, on subsequent requests (which come as part of this template load) this cookie does not seem to be passed on.

I tried loading using:

```
$.ajax("${dataUrl.raw()}",
{
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }, crossDomain: true
}).done(function(data) {
});
```

But his results the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.1.27:9000/carousel/1/data.json. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*').
```

Loading it without the xhrFields loads ok, but the user is not logged on, suggesting the cookie is not passed in the request.
I could optionally include the logon credentials in each data request, but I would prefer just to do it once on startup and give use the cookie with a long lifespan.

**[edit:]**
I tried to add different values for the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', but passing in 'file://' which seems the origin in the case of the call from the local file system does not work as to is said to not match, or chromium says the t'null' is not allowed (which technically I think it is because I have nothing after 'file://'.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a CORS request the server (http://192.168.1.27:9000) needs to allow the use of sending cookies or else an error will be thrown. To enable this the server needs to respond with the following header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

You can read more about this header here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

In addition, can you serve this page from say `localhost`? I'm not sure how `file://` plays with the CORS headers.

Also, make sure you server is passing along this header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The `*` will allow any website but you can scope it to just a single domain.